# AWS EKS configurarion step by step with Linux servers (for kubectl)

Tags: amazon-eks

I am unable to connect EKS Cluster with worker node using kubectl and getting stuck during the connectivity. I have been used the AWS Docs instrcutions & followed up for aws-iam-authenticator and kubectl config while still unable to manage the same, Please help me to share the steps that how can i perform step by step EKS Cluster config and worker node config than most important connectivity b/w cluster and worker nodes using Linux servers (kubectl)

1.I have created IAM role "eksservicerole"
2.Created VPC using cloudformartion (noted down output info)
3.Created EKS Cluster using above created VPC
4.Installed docker and kubectl in one ec2 instance (tried with vmware as well)
5.Facing issue here in connectivity

I should be able to view,create,extend & Reduce the PODs

Answer (score 0):

Are you using EKS optimized [AMI?](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/eks-optimized-ami.html)

If you use this AMI along with the worker node cloudformation, you should have bootstrapping done for you in the UserData section of the cloudformation template. You could try this method and see if the worker nodes joins the master.